# How to Refresh View with Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, query-string

I have a form with a bunch of fields that the user needs to fill out. One part has a textbox that the user puts a Reference Number and clicks the link below to refresh the View with most of the fields filled out.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Copy", "CopyFrom", "Logistics", "",new { onclick = "this.href += '&val=' + document.getElementById('ExistingRefNumber').value;" })
```

Here is the code for the `CopyFrom` `ActionResult`

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CopyFrom(string val)
        {
            int id;
            if (int.TryParse(val, out id))
            {
                var fromModel = new LogisticsModels();
                fromModel = fromModel.GetLogisticsObject(id);

                if (fromModel != null)
                {
                    model = new LogisticsModels();
                    model = fromModel;
                    return View("Index", model);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This all works fine, but what I noticed is that the URL in the address bar has changed from

```
Views/Logistics/Index
```

to

```
Views/Logistics/CopyFrom&val=15551
```

So when the user clicks the Submit button, there's an error because it can't find the CopyFrom view.

What do I need to do to get this to work again?

**EDIT 1**
I got the above to work. The second issue I have with the above is that my form has a submit button that is supposed to call Index(LogisticsModel model) but instead, it's trying to look for Logistics/CopyFrom. This issue only happens when the user clicks on the Copy link as shown above. I'm not sure how to explicitly call the Index ActionResult and pass the model.
 .

Comment: I tried modifying it, but the whole thing stops working. Essentially I just want it to stay on the same page and just fill in the values from the model I created in the Controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is `CopyFrom&val=15551` - the `&` should be a `?`. In a HTTP URL querystring, `?` denotes the start of the querystring and is then followed by the first parameter and its value. Subsequent parameters are then separated from the earlier parameters using `&`, but `&` is not valid to commence the querystring.

So for instance

```
CopyFrom?firstParam=1&val=15551
```

would be a valid way to send *two* parameters to the server.

In your case, you only have one parameter, so you're looking to end up with

```
CopyFrom?val=15551
```

which requires only changing the code

```
"this.href += '&val='
```

to

```
"this.href += '?val='
```

And you should be fine. (N.B. The URL will still change to CopyFrom, but the "Index" view code will be used to render the response, which is perfectly fine.)

If you debug your server-side code, you'll find that the result of your mistake is that `val` is always `null` in the C# because .NET cannot read the parameter from querystring properly (because, as I explained, the querystring is invalid). This will then in turn cause your TryParse to fail, and therefore the action method will return `null` instead of the "Index" view.

---

P.S. you shouldn't really ever return null from an action method - a proper way to handle this would be to return the view but showing an error message - either through a model state error, or just some custom stuff in the ViewBag, or even redirecting to a generic error page (if the problem is not recoverable). You should be able to find plenty of examples of this kind of thing online already. But you should always return *something* to the browser - after all did you ever hear of a web page which just goes blank with no explanation if you make a trivial mistake?

Comment: I got it to work.. but when the user clicks on the Submit button, the call is looking for CopyFrom instead of Index as a View which doesn't help.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what button you're referring to since I can't see any Submit button in your code...but I guess maybe it's part of your Index view somewhere? Anyway, assuming the submit button is within a form, you can easily define your form to post back to a specific action rather than leaving it undefined (and thus defaulting to whatever the current URL happens to be). In other words If it always needs to post to the Index action no matter if the current URL is Index or CopyFrom, then you can explicitly tell it to do that when you define the form in HTML or Razor

Comment: I apologize for lack of info. there's a submit button that is supposed to call Index(FormCollection collection). Instead, it's trying to look for Logistics/CopyFrom which is obviously wrong. I'll update the question to show more information. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I actually figured it out with your help. Thank you so much